# Excel VBA report building

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

I've been working on creating a dynamic report in MS Excel. I'm working on a legacy VB6 application and I've come across a few issue that I hope ya'll can help me resolve. What I'm doing below, is grabbing data into my recordset g_RS3 - typically this has anywhere from 3 to 20 items, and I use g_RS3 to enter values (headings, and 2 column values under each heading: clients, buyers) into my excel spreadsheet. I'm trying to make an edit to it but I've been struggling with it. This is my code....

```
Do While Not g_RS3.EOF
    With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
        .Value = g_RS3("Label")
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = "Clients"
            .Offset(1, 1).Value = "Buyers"
                With .Offset(1, 0)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Offset(1, 1)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Resize(1, 2)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .WrapText = True
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
    End With
    xlCol = xlCol + 2
    g_RS3.MoveNext
Loop
```

I am attaching an image that will show what it looks like. At the end of the recordset I'm trying to add another heading that just says TOTAL and has the 2 columns below it. But I'm having a difficult time doing that.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be a pivot table? Just dump your raw data into a worksheet, and pivot it. No?

Comment: Not sure. I'm pretty much 95% done with the report, I just had a request that a TOTAL heading would help to take all the totals. Just trying to see how I can add it dynamically at the end of my recordset.

Comment: Side question: if `g_RS3` contains *headings*, then why isn't it called `rsHeadings` or something?

Comment: Because g_RS3 is being reused in many cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where it makes sense to extract a stand-alone piece of functionality from your main code: the header block formatting can go into a separate Sub, so you can call it either from within the recordset loop or for a single set of headings

Main code then becomes

```
'headers from recordset
Do While Not g_RS3.EOF
    DoBlock xlsheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol), g_RS3("Label"), "Clients", "Buyers"
    g_RS3.MoveNext
    xlCol = xlCol + 2
Loop
'Extra header
DoBlock xlsheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol), "Total", "Clients", "Buyers"
```

Extracted code:
EDIT - tidied up

```
Sub DoBlock(rng As Range, h1, h2, h3)
    With rng
        .Value = h1
        .WrapText = True
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        .Offset(1, 0).Value = h2
        .Offset(1, 1).Value = h3

        With .Resize(2, 2)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
        .Resize(1, 2).Merge
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just adding one more WITH statement to add the TOTAL cells after your loop would do it.  xlCol should already be pointing to the next column based on the last part of the loop (xlCol = xlCol + 2), so I believe this should work.

```
Do While Not g_RS3.EOF
    With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
        .Value = g_RS3("Label")
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = "Clients"
            .Offset(1, 1).Value = "Buyers"
                With .Offset(1, 0)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Offset(1, 1)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Resize(1, 2)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .WrapText = True
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
    End With
    xlCol = xlCol + 2
    g_RS3.MoveNext
Loop

    With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
        .Value = "TOTAL"
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = "Clients"
            .Offset(1, 1).Value = "Buyers"
                With .Offset(1, 0)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Offset(1, 1)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Resize(1, 2)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .WrapText = True
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
    End With
```