# Excel report - formulas VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a little difficulty with something on my report that I'm building in VB6. Bascially I'm building a dynamic report where the Headings, and 2 columns (clients, students) get populated from a recordset. As you can see in the picture, at the end of my headings, I added a TOTAL heading with clients and students below. I'm trying to take a total of all clients in each of the columns and have it be summed up under TOTAL, same with students. The number of columns (UCLA, SDU, SCCU) might vary, so I'm trying to make it dynamic.Basically start with total for A, then B, then C, D and NONE. Any ideas?
[image]
EDIT: I select the SHORT LABEL from SQL SERVER and populate until g_RS3 is empty

```
Do While Not g_RS3.EOF
    With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
        .Value = g_RS3("ShortLabel")
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = " Clients "
            .Offset(1, 1).Value = " Students"
                With .Offset(1, 0)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Offset(1, 1)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Resize(1, 2)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .WrapText = True
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            End With
    End With
    xlCol = xlCol + 2
    g_RS3.MoveNext
Loop
With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
    .Value = "TOTAL"
        .Offset(1, 0).Value = "Clients"
        .Offset(1, 1).Value = "Students"
            With .Offset(1, 0)
                .Font.Bold = True
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Offset(1, 1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Resize(1, 2)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .WrapText = True
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
End With
```

Then I start in xlrow = 4 xlcol = 2 and populate the CLIENT AND STUDENT columns with data. The loops I have are quite long. But the user will only view the extract. What they do with it once its generated is up to them. The application gives them an option of adding a SHORTLABEL, which needs to be displayed in the extract once they generate it.

Comment: Which one VBA or VB6 ?

Comment: The [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) will do this; e.g. `=sumifs($b4:$g4, $b$3:$g$3, $h$3)` . Use a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) if you have to perform the calculation in VBA or the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) if you want to keep the formula.

Comment: btw, you are going to have to decide whether to use `CLIENT` or `CLIENTS`. There shouldn't be multiple versions of a criteria.

Comment: [As I said earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588539/excel-vba-report-building#comment58863716_35588539), this would be much, much simpler if you simply dumped your recordset into a worksheet, and created a pivot table for it.

Comment: @jeeped its CLIENTS, my mistake

Comment: @Om3r I'm building the report in VB6

Comment: If you are writing this in VB6 then edit your question to include the relevant section of code.

Comment: Where is the merge command for B2:C2, D2:E2, etc?

Comment: @Jeeped this is vb6 code. I cannot include the excel spreadsheet from work as it has sensitive data. I created a sample spreadsheet to just show what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) or [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) can perform this handily.

In H4 as a standard formula,

```
=sumifs($b4:$g4, $b$3:$g$3, h$3)
```

Fill both right and down.

In VBA as,

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    .range("H4:I8").formula = "=sumifs($b4:$g4, $b$3:$g$3, h$3)"
    'optional revert to values only
    '.range("H4:I8") = .range("H4:I8").values
end with
```

You will have to determine the extents of the clients/students ranges but half of that is done simply knowing where to put the formula (e.g. H4).

**VBA**

I've removed a lot of the redundancy that your original code used. Given that you are not yet populating data into the client/student columns, I've used a method where a Total column(s) is always written to the right complete with formulas. If there is another row set, that Totals will be overwritten and a new one created to the right.

```
Dim xlStartCol As Long
xlStartCol = xlCol
Do While Not g_RS3.EOF
    With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
        .Resize(1, 2).Merge
        .Value = "TEST" 'g_RS3("ShortLabel")
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Clients", "Students")
        .Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
        With .Offset(0, 1)
            .Resize(1, 2).Merge
            .Value = "Total"   'keep writing Total to the right; it will be overwritten if there is another ShortLabel
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Clients", "Students")
            .Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).Formula = _
                "=SUMIFS(" & Range(.Parent.Cells(xlRow + 2, xlStartCol), .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 2, xlCol + 1)).Address(0, 1) & Chr(44) & _
                             Range(.Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlStartCol), .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol + 1)).Address(1, 1) & Chr(44) & _
                             .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol - 1).Address(1, 0) & Chr(41)
        End With
        With .Resize(2, 4)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
    xlCol = xlCol + 2
    g_RS3.MoveNext
Loop
```

Once you have actually populated the data into each pair of columns and know the extents, simply use the [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) to populate the remaining formulas.

[image: xlCol]

I would recommend removing portions of recorded code that are not relevant. Recorded code is very verbose and hampers readability. You might also want to look into the `For XML` method of creating a query in T-SQL. This will expand the columns returned and allow you to use a fields count to determine the extents.

Comment: I have to take the count of clients from 3 of the columns and put it under clients in TOTAL, same with STUDENTS. WIll that let me do that. Also, I need to make this dynamic, basically If a user adds another HEADING, this excel extract will automatically add it, so I cannot specify which column to start at. I can only be certain that the ROW in TOTAL will always be the same as the reports are formatted the same way. COLUMN will depend on how many HEADINGS there are.

Comment: re: *'WIll that let me do tha'* - did you even try before asking? As for dynamic expansion a) it will depend upon how the user puts the new columns in b) you should be more worried about where it ends than where it starts. Seems to me that it will always start in column B. c) I thought the data came from a recordset, not from a user arbitrarily adding new columns wherever they like.

Comment: I've been playing around with it. The users enters it in an application. It gets saved in SQL SERVER. I select the data from there and create the extract in Excel. The extract is for viewing purposes only(for user). It will always start in the same place, the ending column is the issue, because it might vary. I edited the question to show you how i do it.

Comment: Thanks for the code. The code works fine, but with one major exception. My app gets stuck when I get to this part.... If xlApp.Version = "10.0" Then
        xlBook.SaveAs g_SQL 
    Else
        xlBook.SaveAs g_SQL , 56
    End If

Comment: it gets stuck on 56 (file format). Basically I have to restart my application. however, i commented out 56 and when I open it in excel, i get the usual - Incorrect Format error msg, but can see the spreadsheet. The columns are there, the totals are there. I'm saving it in "XLS" format, so I need to use 56 - since all the other reports are done this way.

Comment: I do not see **xlBook.SaveAs** anywhere on this page outside of your recent comment. Putting that aside for a moment, version 10.0 indicates xl2002 which did not have a native [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B). I'm not sure if applying the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx) will help but the old xl2002 should have it in any event.

Comment: i saved it as xlsx with file format 51 and seems to be working.

Comment: it looks like the SUM of students is coming up in clients and SUM of clients is coming up in students' cell. Can you please help me, I have no idea how to chagne it?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just having a hard time understanding the SUMIF formula. I have not stepped into it deep like that. This is the first time I'm working on an excel report.

Comment: so It was a simple edit and it seems to be calculating everything okay. now for the fill down, Could I just include it with the code you edited - the number of Rows where my calculations will go under each column (Clients, Students) is always going to be the same - as can be see in the first image. How would this look? Please help me i'm struggling here. This will complete my report.